# FutureBuilder: prevent rebuilding at each page change

Tags: flutter, dart

How can we prevent FutureBuilder from re-calling its future each time the user switches page (e.g. from BottomNavBar) and re-building itself?
NOTICE: the future has a parameter, so I can't initialize it in `initState`

```dart
FutureBuilder(
   future: getChamp(data.keys.elementAt(index)), // keeps rebuilding on page change
  ...
)

Future getChamp(
    String country) async {
   // some stuff
  
  return snapshot;
}
```

Comment: You need to lift the state of "index" so that it can be referenced in initState.

Comment: index (and data of course) comes form another FutureBuilder, parent of the one we are disclosing about

Comment: [AsyncMemoizer](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/AsyncMemoizer-class.html) - the docs say: "An AsyncMemoizer is used when some function may be run multiple times in order to get its result, but it only actually needs to be run once for its effect"

Comment: @pskink seems good but I can't find any implementation

Comment: Implementation of what?

Comment: @pskink I managed to get it working. But now getChamp executes only for index=0. I'd like it to execute one per index

Comment: so use this: https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.cache/MapCache-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found

```dart
FutureBuilder(
 future: FutureA()
 builder: (context, builder) {
  return WidgetB()
}
)
```

with WidgetB() created in another .dart file, using FutureBuilder and `AsyncMemoizer`